# Oracle multiple cursors with the same "WHERE" clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a script with an embedded PL/SQL that opens a few cursors and loops through records fetched performing some actions.

All cursors have part of their **WHERE** a condition that look like this: `AND table_name IN ('table_one', 'table_two' ... 'last_table_from_a_long_list')`

Because the same list of tables is used everywhere I would prefer not to repeat myself but rather to declare the list of tables somewhere and reuse it in the each cursor definition. Ideally you would put those table names in a real table and everything would work OK; however that script will run in production and creating/dropping tables for this purpose is not an accepted practice. The same restriction would apply about creating a user defined type of `table_name` and another one as a `TABLE OF table_name`.

Just wondering if there are some PL/SQL tricks that would help me achieve the same thing. Repeating the long list of tables a dozen of times would make that code look quite bad. This said my script is an "one off" thing so maybe I am worrying too much. There is still the professional "how to" curiosity though.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: You could indeed use a table, but you wouldn't have to keep creating/dropping it - just create a Global Temporary Table (GTT). The data in the table is only accessible per session, so you don't have to worry about multiple sessions running the same code at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: repeat the code.

Longer answer: not repeating the code is more work than just biting the bullet and dealing with a little less-than-perfectly elegant code.

Longest answer: if you really need to insist on doing this then look into using dynamically-created SQL - build your SELECT statement(s) out of strings, then either use the `OPEN cursor FOR sqlString`, `FETCH cursor INTO...`, and `CLOSE cursor` statements, or for extra karma and a pile of difficulty study up on the DBMS_SQL package - and may C͡͏ţ͘húl͞ḩ̸u҉͝ have mercy upon your soul.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options you can try

**EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**

-- Cursor Example

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = :id';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO emp_rec USING emp_id;
```

Another option is **DBMS_SQL**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DYNSQL AS
  cur integer;
  rc  integer;
BEGIN
  cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, 'CREATE TABLE X (Y DATE)', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  rc := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
END;
```

You can google with these key words and you will find many examples.